# How to send text to an input tag within text-angular tag through Selenium with c#

Tags: c#, angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Below is the code I am trying to post a test for selenium into it....here is the code I am using,

```
 IWebElement xxvalue = webElement.FindElement(By.Id("emailMessageContent"));
 xxvalue.SendKeys("This is only a test");
```

I have tried many of the elements within this to find and send the test message to, none have worked. The input is 'hidden'..so it cannot find that field and enter it... So has anyone ran into this and can tell me how to post information to the textarea or the input? etc..

```html
<div>
  <h3>Email Message Content</h3>
  <text-angular name="emailMessageContent" class="email-content-wysiwyg ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ta-root ng-dirty ng-valid-parse focussed" ta-disabled="!vm.selectedEmailEditable()" ng-model="vm.selectedEmail.CustomText"
    ta-toolbar="[['bold','italics','underline','insertLink'],['ul','ol','indent','outdent']]" id="emailMessageContent">
    <div text-angular-toolbar="" name="textAngularToolbar4562419773867687" ta-toolbar="[['bold','italics','underline','insertLink'],['ul','ol','indent','outdent']]" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope ta-toolbar btn-toolbar focussed">
      <div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default ng-scope" name="bold" unselectable="on" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Bold"><i class="fa fa-bold"></i></button>
        <button
          type="button" class="btn btn-default ng-scope" name="italics" unselectable="on" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Italic"><i class="fa fa-italic"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default ng-scope" name="underline" unselectable="on" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Underline"><i class="fa fa-underline"></i></button>
          <button
            type="button" class="btn btn-default ng-scope" name="insertLink" unselectable="on" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Insert / edit link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default ng-scope" name="ul" unselectable="on" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Unordered List"><i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i></button>
        <button
          type="button" class="btn btn-default ng-scope" name="ol" unselectable="on" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Ordered List"><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default ng-scope" name="indent" unselectable="on" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Increase indent"><i class="fa fa-indent"></i></button>
          <button
            type="button" class="btn btn-default ng-scope" name="outdent" unselectable="on" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" tabindex="-1" ng-click="executeAction()" ng-class="displayActiveToolClass(active)" title="Decrease indent"><i class="fa fa-outdent"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ta-scroll-window ng-scope ta-text ta-editor form-control" ng-hide="showHtml">
      <div class="popover fade bottom" style="max-width: none; width: 305px;">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <div class="popover-content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="ta-resizer-handle-overlay">
        <div class="ta-resizer-handle-background"></div>
        <div class="ta-resizer-handle-corner ta-resizer-handle-corner-tl"></div>
        <div class="ta-resizer-handle-corner ta-resizer-handle-corner-tr"></div>
        <div class="ta-resizer-handle-corner ta-resizer-handle-corner-bl"></div>
        <div class="ta-resizer-handle-corner ta-resizer-handle-corner-br"></div>
        <div class="ta-resizer-handle-info"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="taTextElement4562419773867687" contenteditable="true" ta-bind="ta-bind" ng-model="html" ta-readonly="disabled" class="ng-valid ta-bind ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" style=""> </div>
    </div><textarea id="taHtmlElement4562419773867687" ng-show="showHtml" ta-bind="ta-bind" ng-model="html" ta-readonly="disabled" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ta-bind ta-html ta-editor form-control ng-hide"></textarea><input type="hidden"
      tabindex="-1" style="display: none;" name="emailMessageContent" value=""></text-angular>
</div>
```

Comment: Not that I mind the -1....but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the cursor to be on the field, but when I tried to sendkeys, it said it could not focus on that object, which was strange....but I came across this Selenium command of 'Actions'. Used this and it worked for me.

```
            IWebElement messageContent = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("emailMessageContent"));
            Actions actions = new Actions(Driver.Instance);
            actions.MoveToElement(messageContent);
            actions.Click();
            actions.SendKeys("This is a test");
            actions.Build().Perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the element is hidden, try this:

```
IWebElement xxvalue =  webElement.FindElement(By.Id("emailMessageContent"));

IJavascriptExecutor JE = (IJavascriptExecutor)driver; //your webdriver instance here

//here you define the string to make the element visible
String js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";

JE.ExecuteScript(js, xxvalue);

xxvalue.SendKeys("This is only a test");
```

Comment: It says the element is still not visible...any kind of javascript reload/refersh I should do too?

Answer (score 0):

As you want to send text to the `<input>` tag, to achieve that you can use the following code block :

```
IWebElement xxvalue = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//textarea[@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ta-bind ta-html ta-editor form-control ng-hide']/input[@name='emailMessageContent']"));
String js = "arguments[0].style.display='block'; arguments[0].type='text';";
((IJavascriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript(js, xxvalue);
xxvalue.SendKeys("This is only a test");
```

Note : The *WebDriver* instance in my answer is **driver**

As an alternative, you can also try the following code block :

```
IWebElement xxvalue = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//textarea[@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ta-bind ta-html ta-editor form-control ng-hide']/input[@name='emailMessageContent']"));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", xxvalue)
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].type='text';", xxvalue);
xxvalue.SendKeys("This is only a test");
```

Comment: yes..that seems to be the solution from both of you...I am new to selenium and this is the first time I came across the JavaScriptExecutor, I appreciate both of you pointing this out to me. Looking to get it to work now.

Comment: It says the element is still not visible...any kind of javascript reload/refersh I should do too?

Comment: it still says the element is not visible. And when checking the values of that webelement, it says enabled = true, but displayed=false....

Comment: @GregP Check out my updated answer and let me know the result